# need some help on how to approach project using an abstract class

Tags: c++

Need help creating a program that will perform shuffling on strings. It will read two file;

Steps.txt -- containing several primitive shuffling steps to be applied in sequence. In this initial version, only two kinds of steps will be implemented:
rev -- reverse the string.
cut n -- move the first n characters to the end of the string. (If n is larger than the length of the string, do nothing.)

input.txt containing strings to be shuffled, one per line.
the program should print the result of shuffling each string, one per line (and nothing else). For example, suppose the file steps.txt contains the following:
cut 1
rev
cut 5

and the file input.txt contains a line abcdefgh. Then your program should print dcbahgfe,
which is obtained from the input line via the following steps:
 bcdefgha (from cut 1)
 ahgfedcb (from rev)
 dcbahgfe (from cut 5)

**The intermediate steps should not be printed by the final version of your program.This should be repeated for each line of the input.**

So essentially what i need to do is but i'm confused as to how i would go about doing it;

1. Define an abstract class for a shuffle step. This class should have a pure virtual member function that takes a string and transforms it.
2. Define two derived classes of this class, for the two kinds of shuffle step defined above.

Comment: We can help you if you have a **specific** question. But if you just have no idea what to do, you should re-read the chapters of your C++ book on classes, abstract classes, etc.

Comment: This reads like a polite version of a "Gimme teh coedz!!!" question. Thank you for being polite, but sadly it's not enough to overcome the fact that if we do show you how to do this, you won't learn as much as you would from covering the relevant sections of your text and working through the examples to build an honest-but-hard-won understanding of the material that will be with you for more than time it takes to cut and paste.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're asking what an abstract class is and what a pure virtual member function is.

First off, a class is a group of functions and properties. In the real world we have things that you can consider a class. One example of a class would be a car. The functions on the car could be: stop, go, turn left, turn right, etc. The properties may be: color, make, model, etc.

An abstract class is a class that doesn't have any implementation. It just says what a class should look like. An example of an abstract class would be a vehicle. The class Car would implement the abstract class Vehicle.

A pure virtual method in C++ is one that has no definition. You define a class as abstract by giving it at least one pure virtual method. Here is an example:

```cpp
class Vehicle {
  public:
    virtual void drive() = 0; // The 0 means it's a pure virtual, has no implementation.
}

class Car : public Vehicle {
  public:
    void drive(); // We are saying that we implement drive.
}

void Car::drive(){
  std::cout << "Driving!\n";
}
```

You should read up on classes and abstract classes to get a better understanding.